# Django user information creation problem use User.objects.create_user() in the admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-users

I try to create user with user information like ***first name, last name, bio and hobby***. But it show some problem on admin and saving. On **admin** it only show and save first name and last name but don’t show and save other field.

```
myuser = User.objects.create_user(username,email,password)
myuser.hobby = hobby
myuser.first_name = fname
myuser.last_name = lname
myuser.bio = bio
myuser.save()
```

[image: admin picture]

Answer (score 1):

In your admin.py edit to look like this .. (obviously replace "yourapp" appropriately)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from yourapp.models import Yourapp

@admin.register(Yourapp) # This could be User, whatever the name of your model class is
class YourappAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("id", "first_name", "last_name", "hobby ", "bio")
```